# Update jsonb column in CASE statement: "column is of type jsonb but expression is of type text"

Tags: postgresql

I am working in Postgres 11.4. I have a table with a jsonb column:

```
                       Table "public.feature_bundle_plan_feature"
      Column       |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |    Default    
-------------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+---------------
 plan_feature_id   | integer                     |           | not null | 
 feature_bundle_id | integer                     |           | not null | 
 value             | jsonb                       |           |          | 'true'::jsonb
```

I can store an object directly in the jsonb `value` column like this:

```
insert into feature_bundle_plan_feature(plan_feature_id, feature_bundle_id, value)
   values(1, 1, '{"foo":"bar"}');
```

However, I don't seem to be able to do the same thing inside a `CASE` statement:

```
update feature_bundle_plan_feature set value = case
   when feature_bundle_id=1 then '{"foo":"bar"}'
   end;
```

This fails with:

```
ERROR:  column "value" is of type jsonb but expression is of type text
LINE 1: update feature_bundle_plan_feature set value = case                                         
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What the error message says: `'{"foo"::"bar"}'::jsonb`

Comment: `'{"foo"::"bar"}'` isn't valid JSON.

Comment: @stickybit sorry, have fixed typo, still fails with same error message.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks, that works!

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name curious about why I need to cast to `::jsonb` when inserting inside a `CASE` clause, but not otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue with a jsonb column in my stack using AWS RDS with Postgres + Kysely + GraphQL + Serverless Stack (SST). I was sending a stringified object to the api and expecting to insert it like normal, but to no avail. I looked to [Kysely's tests](https://github.com/kysely-org/kysely/blob/b012bd4115c267a08a472a74c432722027199d0c/test/node/src/postgres-json.test.ts#L41-L66) and noticed they used a raw sql query to actually insert the json, but to my surprise I had the same issue. Luckily I found this thread which reminded me to try casting with `::jsonb` and finally it worked! In general something like this should work if you run into OP's particular error message:

```
SQL.DB.insertInto('table_with_jsonb_column')
  .values({
    jsonb_column: sql`${stringified_json_object}::jsonb`
    ...
  }
```

The precise syntax will of course depend on what ORM you're using, if any, but the main takeaway is this is ultimately a **Postgres** error where you'll need to manually cast the value as json/jsonb, likely with raw SQL if using an ORM. I hope this helps someone!